# Скриншот рабочего окна tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

Как сделать скриншот рабочей области, которая сгенерировалась с помощью библиотеки tkinter?

Comment: в windows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964345/how-to-do-a-screenshot-of-a-tkinter-application

Comment: ну и https://pypi.org/project/pyscreenshot/

Comment: Или не принимайте ответ, если он вам не помог) Не поддавайтесь на давление, делайте так как считаете нужным

Comment: @insolor Я это пишу не для того чтобы автор обязательно принял, я просто знаю, что новые участники не знают как принимать ответы и зачем это надо.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, если для новых участников не очевидно, что нужно делать с ответами - это проблема с функциональностью сайта, по этому поводу стоит задать вопрос на мете. Спамить под каждым вопросом сразу после того как вы дали ответ - это не решение, и это действително выглядит как давление на задающих вопросы.

Comment: @insolor Я хотел предложить на мете сделать для новых участников напоминание о том, что надо принимать ответы, если они решаю т вашу проблему. Но никто это не реализует, если не обратиться на MSE, а на MSE наверняка уже было что-то похожее и мой вопрос закроют как дупликат.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica но вы же этого не знаете точно? Кстати, можно уточнить в чате, может быть действительно было что-то похожее.

Comment: @insolor Хорошо так и сделаю. Я понимаю, что писать это  в комментах — спам и выглядит как давление. Я это делаю не затем, чтобы получить побольше репы, а чтобы участники привыкали к правилам сообщества (хотя против репы ничего ни имею ;)).

Comment: Victor, это немного не то что мне нужно, поэтому я не принял. И да , я знаком с системой stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

[`pip3 install pyscreenshot`](https://pypi.org/project/pyscreenshot/)

```
from pyscreenshot import grab

im = grab(bbox=(100, 200, 300, 400))
im.show()
```

---

[`pip3 install pillow`](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/)

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
snapshot = ImageGrab.grab()
save_path = "your/save/path"
snapshot.save(save_path)
```

---

[`pip3 install pyautogui`](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/0)

```
import pyautogui
screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot('path/to/file.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так, с помощью `tkinter` и `pillow`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from PIL import ImageGrab

root = tk.Tk()
def make_screenshot():
    otx, oty = map(int, root.geometry().split('+')[1:])
    width = int(root.geometry().split('x')[0]) + 50
    height = int(root.geomtry().split('+')[0].split('x')[1]) + 3
    scr = ImageGrab.grab(bbox = (otx, oty, otx+width, oty+height))
    path = fd.asksaveasfilename()
    src.save(path)
tk.Button(root, text = 'Сделать скриншот', command = make_screenshot).pack()
root.mainloop()
```