# Сохранить изображение,которое получилось в окне библиотеке tkinter python

Tags: python, изображения, tkinter, клавиатура, save

Как сохранить изображение из окна tkinter, при нажатии на кнопку s, (новичок в python) или дайте ссылку на полезные статьи по решению данного вопроса

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Скриншот рабочего окна tkinter python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1079912/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0-tkinter-python)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что ТС задаёт вопрос повторно.